# How to check if a row of a Pandas dataframe has a cell with a specific value and if it does modify the last cell?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df`:

| name | age_5_9 | age_10_14 | age_15_19 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | no bones broken | no bones broken | broke 1 bone |
| Bob | no bones broken | broke 2 bones | no bones broken |
| Charles | no bones broken | no bones broken | no bones broken |

I would like to create a column `broke_a_bone` that is `1` when any of the rows has a value 'broke 1 bone' or 'broke 2 bones' in any of the columns `age_5_9`, `age_10_14`, or `age_15_19`; otherwise it should be 0.

It should look like this:

| name | age_5_9 | age_10_14 | age_15_19 | broke_a_bone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | no bones broken | no bones broken | broke 1 bone | 1 |
| Bob | no bones broken | broke 2 bones | no bones broken | 1 |
| Charles | no bones broken | no bones broken | no bones broken | 0 |

I tried to use `.iterrows` or `.apply()` but I just can't seem to make it work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you created the original DataFrame it could be improved by storing the number of bones broken rather than an string description.

Comment: Yeah, not me unfortunately. It's an old medical database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `filter` to select the "age" columns, then check if `any` value per row is not (`ne`) "no bones broken".

Convert the resulting boolean to integer for 0/1:

```
df['broke_a_bone'] = (df.filter(like='age_').ne('no bones broken')
                        .any(axis=1).astype(int)
                     )
```

output:

```
      name          age_5_9        age_10_14        age_15_19  broke_a_bone
0    Alice  no bones broken  no bones broken     broke 1 bone             1
1      Bob  no bones broken    broke 2 bones  no bones broken             1
2  Charles  no bones broken  no bones broken  no bones broken             0
```

Comment: Better than my attempt `df['broke_a_bone'] = (df[['age_5_9', 'age_10_14', 'age_15_19']] == 'no bones broken').all(axis=1).astype(int)`

Answer (score 2):

I'd advise converting everything to numeric:

```
age_cols = df.filter(like='age').columns

df[age_cols] = df[age_cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x.str.replace('\D', '', regex=True)).fillna(0).astype(int))

print(df)
```

Output:

```
      name  age_5_9  age_10_14  age_15_19
0    Alice        0          0          1
1      Bob        0          2          0
2  Charles        0          0          0
```

---

Now, we can sum rows easily!

```
df['num_broken'] = df[age_cols].sum(axis=1)

print(df)

# Output:

      name  age_5_9  age_10_14  age_15_19  num_broken
0    Alice        0          0          1           1
1      Bob        0          2          0           2
2  Charles        0          0          0           0
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use np.where (faster)

```
a1 = df["age_5_9"].isin(['broke 1 bone', 'broke 2 bones'])
a2 = df["age_10_14"].isin(['broke 1 bone', 'broke 2 bones'])
a3 = df["age_15_19"].isin(['broke 1 bone', 'broke 2 bones'])

df['broke_a_bone'] = np.where((a1|a2|a3), 1, 0)

#or:
a1 = df["age_5_9"].eq(['no bones broken'])
a2 = df["age_10_14"].eq(['no bones broken'])
a3 = df["age_15_19"].eq(['no bones broken'])

df['broke_a_bone'] = np.where((a1&a2&a3), 0, 1)
```

Comment: I think it's better to test for `no bones broken` because what if there were `broke 3 bones`?

Comment: yes, if you think so, I updated the answer